# Probability of picking a certain order of a box with balls.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

so the question is the following!
We choose **5 balls** one after the other from a box that has  **60 numbered balls** 1, 2, ..., 60, without putting them back. The indications of the balls that are randomly chosen are k1, k2, ..., k5, in the order they were picked.
a. What's the probability of the following: **k1 < k2 < k3 < k4 < k5** ?
b. What's the probability of the following: **k5 > max{k1, k2, k3, k4}** ?

For a: I thought that basically we want 5 items(balls) in a specific order out of 60 balls: 60!/(60-5)!

Answer (score 1):

All orderings of the $k_i$ are equally likely, so the probability of the specific ordering described in (a) is one out of the number of orderings, or $\frac{1}{5!}.$ [Note also that $\frac{60!}{(60-5)!} > 1,$ so you probably meant something different than what you wrote.]

Similarly, each is equally likely to be the largest, so the chance that $k_5$ happens to be largest is $\frac{1}{5}.$

The 60 seems to be a red herring since we only care about relative positions.

Comment: Hmm, I think I get it. So, we basically don't "care" about the 60 balls of the box, since what it asks us is simply what's the order of the 5 balls chosen.

Comment: @Belf Yep! Whether there are 60 balls, or 5, or 1000, the 5 you pick are in some order, and all orders are equally likely. Note that a common variation on this problem is to ask something about the _sum_ of the numbers on the balls, in which case the possible range of numbers certainly does matter, and not all possible outcomes are equally likely.